# Joi "or" operator thinks an empty string is a valid input

Tags: node.js, joi

I am trying to use the "or" operator in Joi ver.17.4.0

As you can see, in the code below, I want either or both of the attributes/properties to be allowed, but not neither.

The problem is that Joi does not allow a string to be empty. So, to have it empty, I need to:

```
Joi.string().allow('')
```

This makes it not empty according to the "or" operator. So I can not get the 'name' to be empty in the eyes of "or".

It won't validate properly.
It validates even when I do this (but it shouldn't):

```
validatePerson(createPerson(''));
```

Keep in mind that I'm actually validating POST input on a node express API, so this is some simplified code to illustrate the issue:

```
const Joi = require('Joi');

function createPerson(name, age) {
  const person = { name: name, age: age };
  console.log(person);
  return person;
}

function validatePerson(person) {
  const schema = Joi.object({
    name: Joi.string().allow(''),
    age: Joi.number(),
  }).or("name", "age");
  console.log(schema.validate(person));
  return schema.validate(person);
}


validatePerson(createPerson('')); // This should fail validation but doesn't
validatePerson(createPerson()); // Should fail and does
validatePerson(createPerson('Bob')); // Should pass and does
validatePerson(createPerson('', 7)); // Should pass and does
validatePerson(createPerson('Bob', 7)); // Should pass and does
```

Comment: As per your `or("name", "age");` you are allowing object to pass validation when either name with empty string .So this will pass

Comment: Why would this `validatePerson(createPerson(''));` fail? You are allowing an empty string as name.

Comment: @soltex, read again. It does pass. It should fail, an empty string is definitely not going to be someone's name in a POST

Comment: @Sohan Joi insists that strings not be empty, so I have no choice but to use an empty string. This causes the "or" operator to become useless. That's why I am asking if anyone knows how to deal with this.

Comment: @Timbokun if an empty string is not going to be someone's `name` as you said, why are you allowing it to be empty? Following your examples, `name` can only be empty if `age` exists?

Comment: @soltex thanks for the input, I will receive a JSON object from a post, so I can't send undefined (which is what I need). Anyway, I realise I will need to do this on the client side. Thanks.

Comment: If the name is mandatory, then yes, you should do this on the client-side. This way, the server will always receive the name. Otherwise, you can change your schema to match your options. For instance: `name: Joi.string().when('age', { is: Joi.exist(), then: Joi.allow('') })`. When `age` exists, you are allowing the `name` to be empty, so your first example will fail as you expected.

Comment: @soltex this is the answer, nice one!

Comment: I just added an answer so it would be easier to help someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want to allow the `name` to be empty an string, only if the `age` exists.

To acheive that, you can use [.when](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#anywhencondition-options):

```
name: Joi.string().when('age', { is: Joi.exist(), then: Joi.allow('') })
```

This way, your first example will fail as you expected.